# Racing condition in assignment to variable of unknown scope

Tags: openmp

a parallel procedure computes the scalar product of two vectors in the following way

1. Compute the contribution of the current MPI process using OpenMP reduction. The result is stored in the SHARED variable `s_loc`
2. OpenMP master calls MPI_Allreduce to compute the sum of s_loc over all MPI processes. The result is stored in the SHARED variable `s_glob`
3. Finally, `s_glob` is assigned to the procedure output argument:
   `s = s_glob`

Note that the scope of `s` is unknown, because it is defined outside the procedure. In the PRIVATE case, the assignment is just per thread and all is fine. However, if `s` is SHARED, a racing condition occurs, since `s_glob` is SHARED. I wonder if this racing condition may pose any problem and, if so, how it could be avoided.

In the following example the MPI part is removed, because it is important only for the scope of variables, but not for the problem itself.

```
program Scalar_Product
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: n = 10000000
  real, save :: a(n), b(n)
  real :: ab

  call random_number(a)
  call random_number(b)

  !$omp parallel private(ab)
  ab = ScalarProduct(a, b)
  !$omp end parallel

contains

  real function ScalarProduct(a, b) result(s)
    real, intent(in) :: a(:) ! left operand
    real, intent(in) :: b(:) ! right operand

    real, save :: s_loc, s_glob
    integer :: i

    !$omp master
    s_loc = 0
    !$omp end master

    !$omp do reduction(+:s_loc) schedule(static)
    do i = 1, size(a)
      s_loc = s_loc + a(i) * b(i)
    end do

    !$omp master       ! in the real application
    s_glob = s_loc     ! s_glob is computed using
    !$omp end master   ! MPI_Allreduce

    ! this is the assignment to which the question refers
    s = s_glob

  end function ScalarProduct

end program Scalar_Product
```

Thanks for any helpful comments!

Joerg

Comment: Please show us some code, because it's hard to understand the scope of the OpenMP parallel regions from your description. Is everything inside a parallel region or not?

Comment: Hi Jim, I edited my question added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I revised the example and think that answers my question.

```
program Scalar_Product
  integer, parameter :: n = 10000000
  real :: a(n), b(n), ab

  ! skipping initialization of a and b ...
 
  !$omp parallel shared(a,b) private(ab)
  ab = ScalarProduct(a, b)  ! would give a racing condition, if ab is shared
  !$omp end parallel

contains

  function ScalarProduct(a, b) result(s)
    real, intent(in) :: a(:) ! left operand
    real, intent(in) :: b(:) ! right operand
    real, save       :: s    ! force result to be shared
    integer          :: i

    !$omp master
    s = 0
    !$omp end master

    !$omp do reduction(+:s) schedule(static)
    do i = 1, size(a)
      s = s + a(i) * b(i)
    end do

  end function ScalarProduct

end program Scalar_Product
```

Observations

- By declaring the function result `save` it becomes shared
- This allows to eliminate the problematic assignment inside the function
- However, as the function is called inside a parallel region, its result must be assigned to a private variable to avoid a racing condition

Cheers, Joerg

Comment: Yes, I think that is a reasonable analysis, however as is the outer code doesn't do anything with the result, (which is in the thread private variable in each thread), so it's still hard to tell if this solves your real problem!